# How do I export table "practices" from db1 into db2? How do I do all tables from db1 into db2? Mysql

Tags: mysql, export, sql

How do I export table "practices" from db1 into db2? How do I do all tables from db1 into db2?

With Mysql, fill in the blank. What do I type at the prompt:

```
Mysql>
```

Comment: Why are you asking first for one table then for all tables? Is there a specific issue you're working on or is this something like a homework problem?

Comment: @Bartimus: I anticipate doing both in the near future and thought I'd avoid doing 2 separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new table in DB2 that's a copy of practices in DB1:

```
Mysql> USE DB2;
Mysql> CREATE TABLE practices SELECT * FROM DB1.practices;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `db2`.`practices` SELECT * FROM `db1`.`practices`
```